# For any prime $p$ and any non-zero $a \in \mathbb{F}_p$, prove that $p(x) = x^p-x+a$ is irreducible and seperable.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

> For any prime $p$ and any non-zero $a \in \mathbb{F}_p$, prove that $f = x^p-x+a$ is irreducible and seperable.

Now, I believe you can show irreducibility of $f$ this way:

$f \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is irreducible

$$\iff$$

$\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ acts transitively on the roots of $f$.

Specifically, by looking at the frobenius endomorphism $x \mapsto x^p$ in $$\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_p(r)/\mathbb{F}_p)$$

and since $\mathbb{F}_p(r)$ I believe is finite, we have that the frobenius endomorphism is surjective, hence an isomorphism, hence in $$\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_p(r)/\mathbb{F})$$ and one finds that it act´s transitively on the roots, which in thise case are $r,r+1,\ldots,r+(p-1)$ for some root $r$ of $f$. Since it means that $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p(r)[x]$ it must be irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ (if I am not mistaken).

Now, I believe there should be a way of showing that $p$ is irreducible without relying on galois.

In particular, you should be able to look at derivatives of $p(x)$. But I am finding it very hard.

Any hints/or solutions would be welcome.

To be clear, I believe I can show seperable, so this question is specifically asking about the irreducibility.

Comment: Your terminolgy is a bit confusing.  What do you mean by "a non-zero prime $a\in \mathbb F_p$"?  And I suggest not using both $p$ and $p(x)$.

Comment: To your question, see [Artin Schreier Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory).

Comment: @lulu better now?

Comment: Your header still refers to a "non-zero prime", but I'll fix that.

Comment: Oh, Yeah, maybe I missed that.

Comment: As the link suggests, stronger results are available.  In general, if your field  $\mathbb K$ has characteristic $p>0$ then that polynomial is irreducible unless $a=b^p-b$ for some element $b\in \mathbb K$.  If $\mathbb K=\mathbb F_p$, you get your claim.

Comment: Isn't easier (in fact, much easier imo.) tto show separability of the polynomial $\;f\;$ by showing $\;f'(x)\neq 0\;$ ?

Comment: Yeah, if you can show irreducibility then yes, true, it follows that if $f'(x) \neq 0$ then $f$ separable!  Good point.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, thanks